# Excel vba - rows to columns and keeping first columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am doing a plan for an year, where I have the labels in the first 3 columns and then the values for the 12 months in the next columns. I want to put the values one under another for the 12 months and to repeat the labels for each month then to go on the next record. I believe there should be a loop for it, but I am not sure how to make it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3ZEV.png)

My data looks like the one in table A on the screenshot
I have to make it to look like table B on the screenshot

Comment: ....but what? =). Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. I got a feeling there is a question behind "but..." which you need to clarify. Include sample data, expected output, your current code and where you get stuck.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't provide any sort of information.  Make an example and attach that as a screenshot

Comment: Not sure about what you want, but I would incline to suppose that you need to study the Transpose function which is able to transform rows in columns and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move/copy the values of a row in a column you can use Transpose function like in my next code example:

```
   Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
   Set rng1 = Range("A1:H10"): Set rng2 = Range("J1:J8")
   arr1 = rng1.value
   arr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr1)
   rng2.value = arr2
```

The code can be optimized, of course, in order to automatically determine the columns number of the row to be transposed and build the column range based of it. I would like to receive a little feedback confirming (or not) that this is what you really need. At least, this is what I could suppose looking to your attached pictures...
The sample code will transpose the content of the (first) row (`Range("A1:H10")`) to the column J:J (`Range("J1:J8")`).